# How to find a control in a separate user control in the same page where it is registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-user-controls

I have two user controls, in one of them I have a textbox, i need to retrieve its value from the second user control which is registered in the same page. How can i do this? I know the following line is wrong.. but i recall it was something like that.

```
TextBox myText = (TextBox)FindControl["mycontrol"] as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access the value of the second control from the first control

```
var textBox = this.Page.FindControl("SecondUserControl")
                  .FindControl("tbCardNumber") as TextBox;
```

Where *SecondUserControl* is the id given in the page and *tbCardNumber* is the id given for the TextBox in the second control

If you try to access the TextBox from a page

```
var textBox = SecondUserControl1.FindControl("SecondUserControl")
                                .FindControl("tbCardNumber") as TextBox;
```

Where *SecondUserControl1* is the ID of the control and you can access it in code behind.

However, you can expose the the value of the text box via a property

```
public string TextBoxValue
{
   get
    {
        return tbCardNumber.Text;
    }
}
```

But you would still need FindControl method if you access it via another user control

Answer (score 1):

The code you have should work, except you have too many casts

```
TextBox myText = FindControl["mycontrol"] as TextBox;
```

[MSDN documentation on FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) which returns a `Control`, which is the base class of [the Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx), so this cast should work as long as the control found is a textbox